# Is it possible to access Emulating Data EEPROM of PIC32 using another PIC microcontroller?

Tags: pic, arm, linux

I tried to use Flash memory of PIC32MX as eeprom (some address) to store data using [microchip library](http://www.microchip.com/SWLibraryWeb/product.aspx?product=Data%20EEPROM%20Emulation%20for%20PIC) , Is it possible to access created eeprom using another PIC32 microcontroller(i2c) or ARM ?

Comment: Through some kind of communication protocol implemented by you, then yes. Otherwise... What...???

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put the PIC into programmig mode and read whatever you want using the programming protocol (provided that it is not fonfiguread as read-protected). This protocol is documented in the programming specification for the chip.